Can you show the date range entered at query level in fields in a report?
Sorry if this is very basic.
I have a standard query that requests a date range
[Date of action]) Between [Enter Date Range: Enter First Date:] And [Enter Last Date:
I would like so show these dates in the report that uses this query.
So I have put 2 fields in the report but I cannot figure out how to link them to the provided dates when generating the query.
Can someone help please.

I am using MS ACCESS
